# Ajax Loader showing twice in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash, bind

I have created a fiddle here...https://jsfiddle.net/qukhn4uk/

As you can see, I have an object for clicking on a grid image that opens a flyout and loads that person's data through ajax (you won't see the data load in the fiddle obviously but you get the idea).  Everything works good here.  The object that handles this is:

```
Stories = {
    flyout: '#flyout',
    closeFlyout: '#flyout .close-flyout',
    storyTrigger: '.story .story-trigger',
    ajaxContentContainer: '#flyout .content',
    loader: '<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>',
    body: 'body',
    init: function() {
        $(this.storyTrigger).click(this.showStory.bind(this));
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(document).on("click", this.closeFlyout, this.closeStory.bind(this));
    },
    showStory: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target),
            targetName = target.data("name");
        $(this.flyout).css("transform", "translateX(-100%)");
        $(this.body).css("overflow", "hidden");
        $(this.ajaxContentContainer).append(this.loader);
        $(this.ajaxContentContainer).load("/story/" + targetName);
    },
    closeStory: function() {
        $(this.flyout).css("transform", "translateX(100%)");
        $(this.ajaxContentContainer).empty();
        $(this.body).css("overflow", "auto");
    }
}
```

I then have another load function for opening the flyout and loading the data based on a hash in the url.  This is the object that handles that...

```
DirectStory = {
        storyDiv: '.story',
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            if ( window.location.hash != '' ) {
                $(this.loadStory.bind(this));
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        },
        loadStory: function() {
            var hash = window.location.hash,
                story = hash.substring(1);
            targetStory = $(this.storyDiv).find("[data-name='" + story + "']");
            targetStory.click();
        }
    }
```

Everything works great but there is one tiny glitch.  For some reason, the DirectStory object is causing the ajaxLoader from the Stories object to load twice.  Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?  Thanks!

UPDATE: I have figured out that the targetStory.click() is running twice inside of the DirectStory object.  I have tried to unbind it first but that does not help. Why is it running twice?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this for anyone who lands here...

The targetStory variable was finding two triggers with the way I was storing it.

I simply updated the targetStory variable to...

targetStory = $(".full-link[data-name='" + story + "']");